# FCM web push message received in DevTools, but event not dispatched

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been working in bulk web push notifications, migrating from OneSignal to Firebase. I've created a single FCM topic to which all users are subscribed immediately on startup.

At first messages arrive on the browser and the notification is shown correctly, but randomly after a few hours and in some devices, notifications cease to show. I've been recording every push message received using DevTools, and noticed that the messages are being received but the push event not dispatched in those cases.

In which cases something like this may happen? It's worth noting that the service worker has been healthly with no errors whatsoever.

Thanks